# Fee error on d7000 with 50 mm lens

Tags: lens, nikon, nikon-d7000, error

I've been reading up solutions for the above error that I've been having and the solution being to set the aperture of the lens to f22 did the trick. My lens hasn't been moved from the locked position of f22 but I still get that error!

Can anyone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Huh? What's a "fee" error.  Who is paying what fee to whom?

Comment: @OlinLathrop FEE is a Nikon error code that is displayed in the top LCD for an error that indicates the camera and lens aren't communicating properly.

Comment: Can you tell us exactly which 50mm lens this is?  A picture would be amazing if you don't know the specifics.

Answer (score 1):

From [Nikon](https://support.nikonusa.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/2605/%7E/what-does-the-fee-or-f---error-message-displayed-on-an-slr-camera-mean?):

> The F-- error message is indicating the camera and lens are not communicating. Either the lens is not designed with electronic contacts, or maybe the lens is not connected fully and clicked in to place. Make sure if the lens is a CPU lens, that it is completely connected onto the cameras bayonet lens mount. Also, be careful not to press the lens release button as this may cause the error. Rotate the lens to lock in place.
>
> You will hear a "click" when the lens is locked in place.
>
> If the problem only occurs occasionally and intermittently, the lens pins and/ or camera contacts may be dirty. Inspect the lens contacts for grease or dirt and wipe them clean with a lint free cloth.

If setting the aperture at maximum aperture isn't doing the trick, then check the electrical contacts on the lens and on the camera mount to be sure they are clean and the spring-loaded contacts on the lens are all functioning properly.

If you have an older lens that is not CPU compatible, you will only be able to use the lens in **Manual** shooting mode.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an old lens ? If so, you may need to use your body in M (manual) mode only, as the body will not be able to handle the lens with electronics.