# Why am I getting "F--" when I format my SD cards on my Nikon D7100?

Tags: nikon, error

I just purchased a Nikon D7100 and when I format the cards with the menu buttons, it tells me the cards are formatted, but I still have the `F--` flashing on the top of my screen. If I use the 2 button shortcut method, `FOR` comes up and I quickly press the 2 again and it immediately goes back to the `F--`. Do I have a bad camera? I need it for graduation pictures in 2 weeks and getting really nervous. I have also tried other working SD cards other than the brand new one just purchased.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aperture message : F ---- when focus to press shutter release](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50011/aperture-message-f-when-focus-to-press-shutter-release)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fee error on d7000 with 50 mm lens](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/41114/fee-error-on-d7000-with-50-mm-lens)

Comment: @MichaelClark Are `FEE` and `F--` synonymous?

Comment: @mattdm They're close enough that Nikon includes both on the same help page: https://www.nikonimgsupport.com/ni/NI_article?articleNo=000001426&configured=1&lang=en_US

Comment: @MichaelClark That link doesn't work without a "Nikon Account". But, anyway, should we make a canonical "nikon FEE/F-- error" question?

Comment: I don't have a Nikon account and it worked fine for me...

Comment: @MichaelClark I see the login screen as well. Is it possible you have used a Facebook or Google login to sign on to Nikon's site? ref: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tomqt.jpg

Comment: I don't think I have. The page just loads for me. No login screen.

Comment: When I go to the link, if I hover over "My Account" it says, "Welcome, Guest. Sign in or create an account to access your information."

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem with formatting your card. The camera is having trouble communicating with the lens. See [Why do I get "F - -" on my Nikon camera?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50011/aperture-message-f-when-focus-to-press-shutter-release/)

Comment: Is "F--" a bad word? Xo) Just a joke.

Comment: @Rafael That's the "F-dash-dash-dash" word, not the "F-dash-dash" error code.